# PDF Viewer with portable bookmarks like Foxit Reader under Windows

Tags: 14.04, pdf

I use Windows as my main OS, and there I have Foxit PDF Reader to open `.pdf` files. In Foxit reader, there is a facility for bookmarking pages that can last even when reinstalling the system, or moving documents from one PC to another.

But in Ubuntu, when I using Evince for reading `.pdf` files and I place a bookmark on some page, when I move the document over to another PC, I lose my bookmark.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You know you can install foxit on Linux right?

Answer (score 2):

Head over to [Foxit software](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/), in the filed that says "Foxit reader", click "Desktop Linux", set the fields as in the following screenshot:

[image]

and click the "open with /usr/bin/software-center" and OK and follow the instructions on-screen!

Comment: And as you're a pretty new user here: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Foxit is available for Linux? o_O